# Postgresql Compare varchar and time type

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I need to make a LEFT JOIN between two columns that are different in data type. One of them is `varchar` and the other is `time`

```
LEFT JOIN my_table ON r.varchar_time = my_table.time
```

How can I compare them, by using to_char?

Comment: You really ought to provide some sample data with this question, or we have to guess what it looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type conversions may use an abbreviated syntax such as `::time` so, you may be able to use:

```
LEFT JOIN my_table ON r.varchar_time::time = my_table.time
```

However if there are any values that don't convert to time that may error. You might go in the opposite direction, but now you must ensure that the format produced by the varchar conversion matches the other column's format.

```
LEFT JOIN my_table ON r.varchar_time = my_table.time::varchar
```

Either way you have potential problems. Ideally that varchar column would be time as well.

The other possible issue I see with this is that time precision might be a problem as well, but this depends on how you populate the columns.

test:

```
select
      (current_timestamp::time)::varchar "varchar"
     , current_timestamp::time "time"

+-----------------+------------------+
|     varchar     |       time       |
+-----------------+------------------+
| 00:50:20.703713 | 00:50:20.7037130 |
+-----------------+------------------+
```

As you can see from this test the "format" of your varchar data will matter

Comment: This one works, I have no error but the result of what I'm selecting is empty, but that has to be a problem with my joins. In the end, I had to use this: `LEFT JOIN my_table ON extract(hour from r.varchar_time::time) = extract(hour from my_table.time)`

Comment: This was the answer that helped me most. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres has functions to convert [from one datatype to another](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/functions-formatting.html). From the docs:

`to_timestamp(text, text)` , timestamp with time zone, converts string to time stamp

Example: `to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')`

Your code might look like this, using whichever format you need to match the other column.

`LEFT JOIN my_table ON to_timestamp(r.varchar_time, 'HH:mm:ss') = my_table.time`

Comment: I got this: [Err] ERROR:  operator doesn't exists: timestamp with time zone = time without time zone